# Get time since comment was posted [Praw]

Tags: python, reddit, praw

Is there a way to get the time since a comment was posted using Praw?

I've looked over the docs but couldn't find any mention of it, if there isn't, are there any workarounds to get the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if you're still looking for an answer. In any case, someone might find this via search engine, so here's an idea:

```
import praw
import datetime

reddit = praw.Reddit(...)
comment = reddit.comment(id="ctu29cb")

now = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.today()))
then = int(comment.created)
delta = now - then

print("comment has been created with timestamp", then)
print("which means on", datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(then).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
print("that was", delta, "seconds or", str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=delta)), "hours ago")
```

which returns

> ```
> comment has been created with timestamp 1438924830
> which means on 2015-08-07 05:20:30
> that was 69533363 seconds or 804 days, 18:49:23 hours ago
> ```